# How can I cheaply travel from Brussels South Charleroi Airport to Bruges?

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, belgium, bruges, crl

How can I cheaply travel from "Brussels South Charleroi Airport" to Bruges? I think the cheapest method would be to take a train. I just don't know where the nearest train station is and how I can get there from airport. Where can I buy ticket? Could somebody please show me the location of the train station on the google map? Where can I find the train schedule? Would buying train ticket online be better than buying ticket at the station? Google map failed to show me the transit directions from airport to Bruges.

Comment: Have you tried typing in those two points in Google Maps? It's pretty good, and would show you the location of the station on the map...
Yes it may not show you transit directions, but that's a different question and depends on the route you're taking.  Also, what is 'cheaply'? If you're taking train, there's likely only one price, whether cheap or not.  Could you perhaps update your question after having anther look at [help], it's likely to be put on hold at present.

Comment: Yes I have tried that before asking here @MarkMayo, and it didn't help as much as it did for other destinations, so I asked here to make sure I know everything about train tickets in Belgium. As you see from the answer, there are more than one price. The one checked online was 20 Euro with Belgium normal trains. I'd go for sth cheaper if available.

Answer (score 8):

This really isn't very complex. If only because, once in Charleroi, you could just follow the crowds. And, because of Google. [Here](http://www.charleroi-airport.com/en/acces/train-bus/index.html) is the information from Charleroi's airport website.

If you want to do your trip by public transport, you have to get a public bus from the airport to Charleroi train station. You buy bus tickets from a vending machine on the bus platform. Buses leave infrequently, something like once an hour.

At the Charleroi train station, you can get a ticket to anywhere.

Alternatively, [flibco](https://www.flibco.com) sells direct transfers between Charleroi airport and Brugge from as low as 5 euros. These you should buy early.